# Android Phonegap 2.5.0: Error in building phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, adt

I've done to create a phonegap 2.5.0 project template by following [Getting Started with Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html) on Windows.

I'm using the ADT Bundle IDE from [Get the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). After I setup new Android project from existing code, I get few errors that prevent building the project. I've solved *AndroidManifest.xml*, *main.xml*, *strings.xml*, *config.xml*. But I'm still getting the major error which is

```
Archive for required library: '~/libs/cordova-2.5.0.jar' in project 'xxx' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

Does anyone facing this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things easy, you can create the project by using the command create provided with the phonegap package. Once created, you should be able to directly compile it without any errors.

To answwer your question, make sure you have cordova-2.5.0.jar in your libs. If not, add it using right click on project -> Build Path -> Add external archives. Then choose the jar.